# Printer turns off after heating up the hotend

Tags: nozzle, creality-cr-10, temperature

I have a Creality CR-10 Max. When I start heating up the hotend, it always suddenly turns off.

I did check the resistance of the heater it was about 4 Ω. The heater itself have 40 W and 24 V. So the resistance should be about 14-15 Ω.

Any idea what happened to my printer?